# How to send wsdl request body in activemq using camel route

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

Is it possible to send the wsdl request body in active mq using camel route. If yes who can i achieve this below is my sample code in which im trying to send the wsdl request body in a queue but its not happening.

```
<route id="report">
            <from id="_from2" uri="direct:reportIncident"/>
            <to id="_to3" uri="activemq:queue:in.incident.report"/>
            <process id="_process1" ref="reportIncidentProcessor"/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="log:output"/>
        </route>
```

I got below exception in my fuse.log file

```
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-NISB-TEC-C3880-54427-1496206891706-5-5 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:NISB-TEC-C3880-54424-1496206882676-7:1:1. Exchange[ID-TEC-1496206891706-5-4]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:153)[246:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.17.0.redhat-630077]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:62)[246:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.17.0.redhat-630077]
```

Comment: The message is sent to AMQ, but there is nobody on the other end consuming it and sending the reply within 20 seconds. If you don't want or need the communication to be request-reply, then you need to set the exchange pattern accordingly or [configure the endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) to this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web service call is InOut by default and when you send to the ActiveMQ it conveys that same style so it would expect a reply message which you wont get and therefore you see that exception.

So if you want to send a InOnly (fire and forget) message to the ActiveMQ, then you need to specify that

```
   <to id="_to3" uri="activemq:queue:in.incident.report"/>
```

Should be

```
    <to id="_to3" pattern="InOnly" uri="activemq:queue:in.incident.report"/>
```

See more at:
- http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html
- http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html

Comment: thanks alot @Claus it worked. but who can i get the wsdl request body/parameters in camel route n send them in a queue. getting this exception Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes

Comment: You need to convert the message to a type you can send over JMS such as String or byte[] before sending - see the `convertBodyTo`